How to Convert a Flutter Module into a Standalone Webpage
I’m currently facing an issue with my Flutter project. Right now, it’s built as a module to integrate with native iOS and Android platforms. However, I have been asked to convert these modules into standalone web pages. Since I’m relatively new to Flutter and lack experience, I’m asking for guidance and advice from everyone.
I’ve tried searching, but most resources don’t provide any guidance on converting a module into a webpage. I hope this question will be answered by someone with experience.
